# unable to render font awesome icons from locally placed FA library

Tags: css, firefox

I have downloaded the font-awesome library and linked it to my HTML. Here is the simplest version of my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <i id="search-icon" class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, what is rendered in the browser is:

[image]

What am I missing? I need to get this working in Firefox only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to set encoding of the page first, and then check if all other files are placed in correct directories as `"Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project"` in [get started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) page says.

Comment: I set the encoding as `<meta charset="UTF-8">` but it didnt help. The FA css file is in the same folder as the HTML file.

Comment: You need more files, not just the css. See the get started link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, when you inspect your page and click on the font-awesome.min.css file, is it linked correctly.

Secondly are the font and supporting files that come with FontAwesome sitting in the correct folder (relative to your font-awesome.min.css file)?

For example, unless you altered the CSS in the files they gave you, you need to place the /font directory that comes with FontAwesome up a directory from your CSS files.

See the following as an example of how the CSS is referencing the font files.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.2.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.2.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.2.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Steps: Change your  href to point to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

1. Download the assets for FontAwesome: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome-4.2.0.zip
2. Move both the /css and /fonts folders directly next to your HTML file.

Comment: Yes, the file `font-awesome.min.css` is placed in the same folder as the HTML file. I just downloaded this file from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/. What am I missing? What are the supporting files that I need?

Comment: There are other files needed for FontAwesome to work besides the font-awesome.min.css file. You need to also move the /font folder into your project. I would suggest deleting the css file you moved in and follow my directions in my updated answer above.